# How many segments can be selected from a line with $n$ evenly spaced dots? How many rectangles can be selected from a $m \times n$ rectangle grid?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find expressions for each of the following. (Leave your answer as a mathematical expression rather than a number.)

(a) Consider a line interval on which is placed $6$ evenly spaced dots like the ones shown. How many different line intervals can be drawn having one of the dots as a left endpoint and another dot as a right endpoint? The second diagram illustrates one such interval.

[image: line_with_equally_spaced_points]

(b) Consider a line interval on which is placed $n$ evenly spaced dots. How many different line intervals can be drawn having one of the dots as a left endpoint and another dot as a right endpoint?

[image: rectangular_grid]

c) Consider the $4 \times 5$ rectangle grid shown. Using your answer to (b) as a hint, how many rectangles does this grid contain? (It is also a good idea to test your hypothesis on a smaller grid.)

d) Consider an $m \times n$ rectangle grid. How many rectangles (regardless of size) does this grid contain?

Mind explaining and solving it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck.  Also, please post the diagrams for the question.

Comment: Would degenerate rectangles and line intervals count? E.g. a single dot as begin and endpoint of an interval, or single dot as empty rectangle.

Comment: @Pieter21  It says having one of the dots as a left endpoint and *another* dot as a right endpoint, which excludes degenerate cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider a line interval on which are placed $n$ evenly spaced dots. How many different line intervals can be drawn having one of the dots as a left endpoint and another dot as a right endpoint?

**Hint:** A line segment is determined by choosing its two endpoints.  How many ways can two endpoints be selected from $n$ available points?

> Consider an $m \times n$ rectangle grid.  How many rectangles, regardless of size, does this grid contain?

**Hint:**  A rectangle is determined by choosing two horizontal sides and two vertical sides.  Thus, we must choose two of the horizontal lines and two of the vertical lines in the grid to be the sides.  How many horizontal lines does a $m \times n$ rectangle grid contain?  How many vertical lines does a $m \times n$ rectangle grid contain?

Comment: That is the correct answer for part (a), which you can check by simply listing the $15$ cases.

Comment: is it 6 C 2 ways for the dot to join from one end point to another ?  For the rectangle grid i am a bit confused .

Comment: As I said, the number of ways to form line segments in the first question is $\binom{6}{2}$.  That should give you a good idea of how to solve part (b).  For part (c), notice that a $4 \times 5$ rectangle grid has five horizontal and vertical lines.  We must choose two of the five horizontal lines and two of the six vertical lines for the sides of the rectangle.

Comment: is it something like this for horizontal is 2/5 x (5C1+ 5C2 until 5C5)  and for vertical is  2/6(6C1 + 6C2 until 6C6) then times them up ?

Comment: That is incorrect.  We need to choose horizontal sides and two vertical sides.  There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose two of the five horizontal sides and $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose two of the six vertical sides, so we obtain $\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{2}$ possible rectangles.

Comment: We are not ignoring sizes of more than two.  We are selecting the sides of the rectangle.  There are five horizontal lines from which we select two horizontal sides and six vertical lines from which we select two vertical sides.